# runtime constructor parameter using microsoft DI

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

How can I pass runtime constructor parameter to resolve an object while using Microsoft Dependency Injection.

All that looks possible is to pass the parameter only in the startup while adding the object to the DI.

In Autofac, this is possible but nothing available for Microsoft DI:

```
var reader = scope.Resolve<ConfigReader>(
    new NamedParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName"));
```

Comment: This is often discussed and treated as an anti-pattern so there might not be an easy solution. My suggestion would be to set up a factory service where you can pass the configuration section name and get back the actual service, correctly configured. The reason why this is often an anti-pattern is that you have purposefully selected a system to abstract away your dependencies, but you've at the same time said "But all my dependencies here need to be able to use a configuration section name", they are sort of orthogonal.

Comment: The factory with the same thing also sort of falls under the same anti-pattern, but is often much easier to implement.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying that your specific usage of this falls under the anti-pattern, all I'm saying is that abstract services that have concrete construction parameters (aka dependencies) usually are, and that's why you might not find good support for this pattern in the DI container you're using.